# name and sum from 2 different tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables.
table customer have. id , name , age
table order have . id, customer_id , order_amount , order date.

I want to show all name from customer table and sum of order amount from order table according to customer.

| customer_id | Name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice | 24 |
| 2 | Bob | 52 |
| 3 | Carol | 45 |
| 4 | Dave | 51 |

| order_id | customer_id | order_amount | order_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 50 | 2012-4-5 |
| 2 | 1 | 27 | 2012-8-1 |
| 3 | 2 | 12 | 2013-5-20 |
| 4 | 4 | 25 | 2014-1-25 |
| 5 | 4 | 30 | 2014-5-30 |
| 6 | 1 | 20 | 2014-6-22 |

**EDIT**
I tried this but it gives me only bob and sum of all columns instead of separate sum of customers

```
SELECT customers.name, SUM(orders.order_amount) FROM `orders` INNER JOIN customers WHERE orders.customer_id = customers.customer_id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Joining condition must be on ON clause, not in WHERE.
2. You must specify for what group the sum must be calculated.

```sql
SELECT customers.name, SUM(orders.order_amount) 
FROM `orders` 
INNER JOIN customers ON orders.customer_id = customers.customer_id
GROUP BY customers.name;
```

Comment: what is group by ? why we use that and when i removed it, it does not show answer which is required why ?

Comment: @ehsanhaider GROUP BY divides the whole rowset to separate groups by given expression (in the query - the group contains all orders for separate customer). And the aggregaton is performed in each group separately.